# Convert 2 column table to json object in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table that represents relationships between relatives.

`name1` is the `relationship` of `name2`.

```
name1 | name2 | relationship
-----------------------------
"Joe" | "Mary"| "uncle"
"Sue" | "Mary"| "mother" 
etc.
```

There's a People table, where name is the primary key.

I'd like to perform a query of all `Mary`'s relationships and get the result back as a JSON object, where the key is the name of the other person, and the value is the relationship.

Example:

```
{
    "Joe": "uncle",
    "Sue": "mother"
}
```

Assumptions:
Mary is only in going to be in the name2 row here.
You can't have more than 1 relationship with any other person.

I tried things like json_build_object, and row_to_json, but I can't seem to get the data to take the right shape.

What's the query that I need to achieve this?

Has anyone else done this before?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `json_object_agg` function. See the [documentation on aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

```sql
SELECT json_object_agg(name1, relationship) FROM relatives WHERE name2 = 'Mary';

            json_object_agg
---------------------------------------
 { "Joe" : "uncle", "Sue" : "mother" }
```